# Android put marker on start and end of polyline

Tags: android, arraylist, polyline

Hi I am using Async task to grab longitude and latitude in an JSONArray. I am able to draw polyline but I cannot figure out how to draw put in the start and the end of the polyline.

```
// Initialization
 ArrayList<LatLng> polylines = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
 JSONArray lines = null;
 JSONObject jsonPolyline;
 LatLng polyline;
```

And here is what I have on the `onPostExecute` of my AsyncTask

```
lines = json.getJSONArray("track");
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length(); i++) {
jsonPolyline = lines.getJSONObject(i);
polyline = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(jsonPolyline.getString("lat")),
                            Double.valueOf(jsonPolyline.getString("lon")));
polylines.add(polyline);
}
/*call the polyline */
myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(polylines).width(2.0f).color(Color.GREEN));
```

I tried using , `ListIterator` but since my Arraylist is `<latlng>` , I cannot get the first and last element on the arraylist.

How can I get the first and last element on my arraylist so that I can draw marker on the start and end position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Java `List<>` implements `get()` and `size()` methods:

```
first = polylines.get(0);
last = polylines.get(polyline.size() -1);
```